# How to check if an internal tab is available after refreshing few times?

Tags: angular, protractor

Protractor tests: I have 4 internal tabs in a page. 2 are available by default when the url is opened. When I click on a button in a tab and refresh page(may take around 30 seconds to 15minutes. So cannot use hard wait)the other tab appears. How do I refresh a page at certain intervals for certain time (refresh every 3 seconds for 15 minutes)and look for the tab availability?

I tried the below code. But the browser doesnt refresh at all. I tried browser. refresh() as well which doesnt work

```
let Menu = element(by.xpath("//md-tab-item[text()='Menu']"))

const check = () => {
   browser.waitForAngular()
       .then(browser.sleep(3000))
       .then(browser.driver.navigate().refresh())

   if (Menu) {
       console.log("Menu tab available.")
       callback()
   }
   else {
       console.log("Menu tab not available. Please refresh")
       check()
   }
}
check();
```

This is my HTML of the tab items. The id is dynamic it changes everytime. So have to use text in the locator

```
<md-tab-item tabindex="0" class="md-tab  md-active" ng-repeat="tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs" role="tab" id="tab-item-0" md-tab-id="0" aria-selected="true" aria-disabled="false" ng-click="$mdTabsCtrl.select(tab.getIndex())" ng-focus="$mdTabsCtrl.hasFocus = true" ng-blur="$mdTabsCtrl.hasFocus = false" ng-class="{ 'md-active':    tab.isActive(), 'md-focused':   tab.hasFocus(), 'md-disabled':  tab.scope.disabled }" ng-disabled="tab.scope.disabled" md-swipe-left="$mdTabsCtrl.nextPage()" md-swipe-right="$mdTabsCtrl.previousPage()" md-tabs-template="::tab.label" md-scope="::tab.parent" aria-controls="tab-content-0">Home</md-tab-item>

<md-tab-item tabindex="-1" class="md-tab" ng-repeat="tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs" role="tab" id="tab-item-2" md-tab-id="2" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" ng-click="$mdTabsCtrl.select(tab.getIndex())" ng-focus="$mdTabsCtrl.hasFocus = true" ng-blur="$mdTabsCtrl.hasFocus = false" ng-class="{ 'md-active':    tab.isActive(), 'md-focused':   tab.hasFocus(), 'md-disabled':  tab.scope.disabled }" ng-disabled="tab.scope.disabled" md-swipe-left="$mdTabsCtrl.nextPage()" md-swipe-right="$mdTabsCtrl.previousPage()" md-tabs-template="::tab.label" md-scope="::tab.parent" aria-controls="tab-content-2" style="">Profile<iv class="md-ripple-container" style=""></div></md-tab-item>

<md-tab-item tabindex="0" class="md-tab  md-active" ng-repeat="tab in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs" role="tab" id="tab-item-0" md-tab-id="0" aria-selected="true" aria-disabled="false" ng-click="$mdTabsCtrl.select(tab.getIndex())" ng-focus="$mdTabsCtrl.hasFocus = true" ng-blur="$mdTabsCtrl.hasFocus = false" ng-class="{ 'md-active':    tab.isActive(), 'md-focused':   tab.hasFocus(), 'md-disabled':  tab.scope.disabled }" ng-disabled="tab.scope.disabled" md-swipe-left="$mdTabsCtrl.nextPage()" md-swipe-right="$mdTabsCtrl.previousPage()" md-tabs-template="::tab.label" md-scope="::tab.parent" aria-controls="tab-content-0">Menu</md-tab-item>
```

I dont see any error. But the execution just gets struck in there. Browser is not refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code -

```
async waitForTabLoading() {

  let menu = element(by.xpath("//md-tab-item[text()='Menu']"))
  await browser.wait(async() => await menu.isDisplayed().then(() => true, async function() {
    try {
          await browser.sleep(3000);
          await browser.refresh();
          return false;
        }
      catch (ex) {
             console.log(ex.message); // You can keep it or remove it.
             return false;
           }
        }
        ), 900000); //wait till 15 minutes
        return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: This solution is using the `async/await` syntax for handling promises while it appears that OP is using the control flow. It is probably worth mentioning in your answer the distinction as it is not recommended to mix the two approaches within the same framework